# How to show selected date on line chart plot with x axis in High chart if I have multiple value for single date

Tags: javascript, arrays, highcharts

I am using Highchart , I am new for it , I need to show line chart when i have a selected date array and every date have multiple value.
For Example I have
`date=[2022-01-02,2022-01-07,2022-01-10]`
and
`Data=[[1,2,3],[3,5,4],[6,3,4]]`

I have some references but for column and single data : https://jsfiddle.net/50e1nbac/4/

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxLKF.png)

In above picture I just need to mentioned date from list on X-axis.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have date list and for every date I have multiple data . I need to plot those data on line chart in continuous manner but on x axis I need to show date , In above example , I need to plot 1 then 2 then 3 and on x axis they should show 2022-01-02  at 3 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For showing observation scatter series will be fit to visualize it how many times the action has occurred. You can insert the dates as categories, the points will refer to them.

```js
var dates = ["2019-06-14 17:00:00", "2019-06-14 17:01:00", "2021-04-13 06:15:00"];

Highcharts.chart('container', {
  title: {
    text: 'Scatter plot with regression line'
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    categories: dates
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0
  },
  series: [{
    type: 'line',
    name: 'Regression Line',
    data: [
      [0, 1.11],
      [5, 4.51]
    ],
    marker: {
      enabled: false
    },
    states: {
      hover: {
        lineWidth: 0
      }
    },
    enableMouseTracking: false
  }, {
    type: 'scatter',
    name: 'Observations',
    data: [1, 1.5, 2.8, 3.5, 3.9, 4.2],
    marker: {
      radius: 4
    }
  }]
});
```

```css
#container {
    height: 400px;
}

.highcharts-figure,
.highcharts-data-table table {
    min-width: 310px;
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 1em auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
    <div id="container"></div>
</figure>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9r07asom/

https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/scatter-chart
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.categories

Comment: On axis lable it was showing 3 4 5 after date ,  There should show only date which are mentioned.

Comment: The series responsible for drawing regression line reserved position on yAxis, [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9r07asom/1/).

Comment: Yes you are right but I don't want to define every single value with individual date , I need to plot multiple value with single date. Means date should be work as breakpoint.

Comment: You can define where the tick are laid using options [xAxis.tickPositions](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPositions). In case of that, you will see only a tick if will be related to data -->  [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7yune2ds/)

Comment: Ok fine , it is not pure answer what I want but it is alternate thinking / solution of this prob. Thanks.